# When look up symbol, the program doesn't search from the correct library

Tags: c++, linux, runtime, shared-libraries, dynamic-loading

I'm adding two classes and libraries to a system, `parent.so` and `child.so` deriving from it.

The problem is when the program is loading `child.so` it cannot find parent's virtual function's definition from `parent.so`.

What happens,

`nm -D child.so` will gives something like (I just changed the names)

`U _ZN12PARENT15virtualFunctionEv`

---

The program will crash running

```
_handle = dlopen(filename, RTLD_NOW|RTLD_GLOBAL); //filename is child.so
```

it'll give an error with `LD_DEBUG = libs`

```
symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: _ZN12PARENT15virtualFunctionEv (fatal)
```

The thing I cannot explain is, I tried `LD_DEBUG = symbols` using GDB, when running `dlopen`, the log shows it tried to look up basically in all libaries in the system except `parent.so`, where the symbol is defined. But from libs log `parent.so` is already loaded and code is run, and it is at the same path of all other libraries.

```
 ......
 27510:     symbol=_ZN12PARENT15virtualFunctionEv;  lookup in file=/lib/tls/libm.so.6
 27510:     symbol=_ZN12PARENT15virtualFunctionEv;  lookup in file=/lib/tls/libc.so.6
 27510:     symbol=_ZN12PARENT15virtualFunctionEv;  lookup in file=/lib/ld-linux.so.2
 27510:     child.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: _ZN12PARENT15virtualFunctionEv(fatal)
```

How the program or system is managing which library to look for a symbol's definition?

I'm new to Linux, can anybody point me some directions to work on?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

The command used to generate `parent.so` file is

```
c++  -shared  -o parent.so parent.o
```

Similar for `child.so`. Is any information missing for linking here? Looks like child is only including parent's header file.

**EDIT2**

After another test, calling

```
_handle = dlopen("parent.so", RTLD_NOW|RTLD_GLOBAL);
```

before the crashing line will solve the problem, which I think means originally `parent.so` was not loaded. But I'm still not very clear about the cause.

Comment: Can you load them at build time instead of runtime? Can you paste the command you are using to build?

Comment: Sorry but how exactly do I load them at build time? Thanks.

Comment: And which library you want the build command? Parent or child?

Comment: Does the dynamic load info in child.so actually indicate that parent.so is a needed object? If it isn't it will not get loaded. Which dynamic objects to load is not dependent on the symbols but on the DT_NEEDED entries of each dynamic object (and any dlopens) used.

Comment: *I'm new to Linux* -- so why are you using dynamic libraries loaded at runtime as opposed to at link time? Runtime dynamic libraries are an advanced topic.

Comment: @wich Thanks for the info, but does this DT_NEEDED entry appear in .so files all the time? I use readelf -s child.so but didn't find this entry.

Comment: @DavidHammen, yes, I'm no expert but I have to add stuff to a large system which was written by experienced people, and that's the way for all such libraries.

Comment: @Derek You need to use `readelf -d` to see the dynamic section of a dynamic object, that will show you the DT_NEEDED entries of that dynamic objects, as well as the linker script, the RUNPATH, etc.

Comment: I see, thanks @wich. However, looks using this command the NEEDED entries are same as running `ldd libchild.so`, and it doesn't include `libparent.so`. From my understanding and experience on this problem, seems it's not required. Am I right?

Comment: You have two choices, either you `dlopen` libparent before libchild or you indicate to the linker script that libchild needs libparent with a `DT_NEEDED` dynamic entry, (this is what the `-lparent` option to g++ does.) And `ldd` and `readelf -d` are not the same. `ldd` runs the linker script and shows all requested libraries recursively, while `readelf -d` only shows the direct needed libraries. For example if A needs B and B needs C, then `ldd A` will show B and C, but `readelf -d A` will show only B.

Comment: Thanks a lot @wich for the insight, I now understand it much better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell the linker that your library `libchild.so` uses functionality in `libparent.so`. You do this when you are creating the child library:

`g++ -shared -o libchild.so child_file1.o child_file2.o -Lparent_directory -lparent`

Note that order is important. Specify the `-lparent` after all of your object files. You might also need to pass additional options to the linker via the `-Wl` option to g++.

That still might not be good enough. You might need to add the library that contains `libparent.so` to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

A couple of gotchas: If you aren't naming those libraries with a `lib` prefix you will confuse the linker big time. If you aren't compiling your source files with either `-fPIC` or `-fpic` you will not have relocatable objects.

**Addendum**
There's a big potential problem with libraries that depend on other libraries. Suppose you use version 1.5 of the parent package when your compile your child library source files. You manage to get past all of the library dependencies problems. You've specified that your `libchild.so` depends on `libparent.so`. Your stuff just works. That is until version 2.0 of the parent package comes out. Now your stuff breaks everywhere it's used, and you haven't changed one line of code.

The way to overcome this problem is to specify at the time you build your child library that the resultant shared library depends specifically on version 1.5 of libparent.so`.

To do this you will need to pass options from g++/gcc to the linker via the `-Wl` option. Use `-Wl,<linker_option>,<linker_option>,...` If those linker options need spaces you'll need to backslash-escape them in the command to g++. A couple of key options are `-rpath` and `-soname`. For example, `-rpath=/path/to/lib,-soname=libparent.so.1.5`.

Note very well: You need to use the `-soname=libparent.so.1.5` option when you are building libparent.so. This is what lets the system denote that your libchild.so (version 1.0) depends on libparent.so (version 1.5). And you don't build libparent.so. You build libparent.so.1.5. What about libparent.so? That needs to exist to, but it should be a symbolic link to some numbered numbered version (preferably the most recent version) of libparent.so.

Now suppose non-backward compatible parent version 2.0 is compiled and built into a shiny new libparent.so.2.0 and libparent.so is symbolically linked to this shiny new version. An application that uses your clunky old libchild.so (version 1.0) will happily use the clunky old version of libparent.so instead of the shiny new one that breaks everything.

Comment: Please don't use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, use `RUNPATH` instead

Comment: @wich: Yes, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is a heavy handed kludge. It's better to tell the linker where that other library lives and to build that path into the library. I was answering in the context of someone who is "new to Linux". (And someone new to Linux probably shouldn't be using runtime dynamic libraries.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @DavidHammen, I think at least I get a better picture now. So allow me to ask this clarification question. Dynamically loading libraries (dlopen and dlsym) doesn't require the main program link with .so files, but if different .so have dependencies between each other then they need to link with them during building, is this statement correct? Or am I missing farther?

Comment: And although I'm no Linux guru, but the system I'm adding stuff into is quite complicated. And I do see other similar libraries got built the say way (no additional linking libraries in build command). So is there any other place that might handle this but I was missing?

Comment: Thanks a lot @DavidHammen, this turned out to be the right direction, we finally identified the libparent.so was not loaded at that point and the issue was fixed by modifying Makefile of some libraries used in between main and libparent.so. Thank you also for the information and education. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @DavidHammen even more reason not to introduce `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but `RUNPATH` instead, it's no more difficult to use, especially in the case where the libraries always reside in the same directory since `$ORIGIN` can be used in that case. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has done enough damage in my opinion, it is time for a conscious movement away from it, and that is only possible by educating people in the correct way instead of throwing them to the sharks with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Yes, people should be aware of its existence, but not to the exclusion of `RUNPATH`.

Comment: What is this `RUNPATH` you are speaking of? It's not a standard Linux environment variable, attribute, or option. There's a `LD_RUN_PATH` environment variable which is used at the time the program/library is created. There's a `-rpath` option to the linker/loader. These can set a library's `DT_RUNPATH` attribute. But AFAIK, there is no `RUNPATH`.

Comment: I am talking of the `DT_RUNPATH` ELF dynamic entry, my apologies for not being more specific.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not telling the linker that child.so needs parent.so, use something like the following:

```
g++ -shared -o libparent.so parent.o
g++ -shared -o libchild.so -lparent child.o
```

Answer (score -1):

When you build your main program, you have to tell the compiler that it links with those libraries; that way, when it starts, linux will load them for it.

Change their names to libparent.so and libchild.so.

Then compile with something like this:

```
g++ <your files and flags> -L<folder where the .so's are> -lparent -lchild
```

EDIT:

Maybe it would be a smaller change to try loading parent.so before child.so. Did you try that already?

Comment: Actually the names are libparent.so and libchild.so, I changed it due to unfamiliar with Linux.

Comment: Besides, when running with LD_DEBUG = libs, the log showed parent.so is loaded, and some of its code is running, does it mean the building is correct? or not necessary?

Comment: -1 for *you have to tell the compiler that it links with those libraries* No, you don't. That's the point of `dlopen` and `dlsym`.

Comment: @DavidHammen it is not necessary to load a shared object explicitly at runtime with dlopen. You can do it at compile time which is more common.

Comment: @Nick, You mean link time, not compile time. Derek isn't using that link time resolution for some reason and he didn't say why. All we know is that he is using `dlopen()`.